# Slide 4 documents at a time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I found image slider which slides a single image at a time.

Can anyone please help me how to slide 4 documents or images at a time.

[image]

Is there any plugins available in jquery.

I am using Javascript and jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a fan of http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ myself.

It cycles all the child elements of the container that you call cycle() on, so you just need to make a div that contains your four images:

```
<div id='divCycleMe'>
   <div>
       <table>...Put your images in here</table>
   </div>
   <div>
       <table>...Put your images in here</table>    
   </div>
...
</div>
```